# Other invariants of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

The minimal and characteristic polynomials of a linear transformation encode much useful information about the transformation. Of course, they do not encode all useful information -- for example, we know that two linear transformations are conjugate if and only if they have the same minimal (or characteristic) polynomial *and* the powers of the prime factors of the polynomial applied to the transformations have the same ranks. On the other hand, the matrix of the transformation with respect to a basis (in particular a normal form) encodes all information.

Are there any other "natural" invariant objects associated with a linear transformation, which encode more information than the minimal and characteristic polynomials and are straightforward to study, other than matrix forms?

Comment: Usually we classify linear transformations from a vector space to itself up to similarity. But this is just the Jordan normal form, which you have excluded. So I don't think there is a "better" classification available (using other invariants than minimal polynomials, rank, determinant etc.).

Comment: The trace and the determinant of a linear transformation are also invariants - although they are obviously included as factors in the characteristic polynomial...

Comment: I thought of *algebraic entropy* of a linear map, but it is simply the rank of the associated matrix. I still don't believe that there are new invariants encoding more information than the usual matrix invariants.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thanks for thinking about it. Perhaps I shouldn't be surprised that I haven't seen any others in the linear algebra references I've read, but I thought it worth asking.

Comment: @blargoner This isn't that much a deviation from Jordan normal form, but one invariant that can be considered is $\operatorname{rank}(A - \lambda I)^k$ for $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ and $k = 1,2,3,\dots$. By taking successive differences in this sequence, one obtains the "Weyr characteristic" (a discussion can be found in [this paper](https://works.swarthmore.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1027&context=fac-math-stat) or in Horn and Johnson's *Matrix Analysis*). Just like the Jordan form, Weyr characteristics completely characterize linear transformations up to similarity.

Comment: @blargoner Another complete set of invariants is the set of "invariant factors" associated with the [rational canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) (notably, these do not require an algebraically complete field). The largest of these factors is the minimal polynomial, and their product is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for the references!